GDB How to generate a core dump file?
I always use GDB in an interactive session (gdb --args <program>)
Two questions:

Is it possible to configure .gdbinit to automatically generate the core dump file?

Related to first Q, if the program crashes is there a GDB session command to manually generate the core dump file?




Is it possible to configure .gdbinit to automatically generate the core dump file?

Maybe: configure to generate the core dump when ?

if the program crashes is there a GDB session command to manually generate the core dump file?

(gdb) help gcore
generate-core-file, gcore
Save a core file with the current state of the debugged process.
Usage: generate-core-file [FILENAME]
Argument is optional filename.  Default filename is 'core.PROCESS_ID'.

Update:

i'd like to auto-generate the core file on receiving a SIGABRT/segmentation fault etc?

The only way I know is to set up a signal handler for all signals of interest, set a breakpoint on the signal handler, and add commands to that breakpoint. Something along the lines of:
struct sigaction sa{};
sa.sa_handler = my_handler;
sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, NULL);
sigaction(SIGABRT, &sa, NULL);
...

(gdb) break my_handler
(gdb) commands $bpnum
gcore
end

(Above commands should work from ~/.gdbinit as well.)

In response to your question: i'd like to auto-generate the core file on receiving a SIGABRT/segmentation fault etc? Anything where the program cannot continue

@intrigued_66 I've updated the answer.

Would catch signal not work for this?

@ssbssa Looks like you are right: "One reason that catch signal can be more useful than handle is that you can attach commands and conditions to the catchpoint."
